# Obj-C setValuesForKeysWithDictionary 64-bit vs 32-bit

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary, 32bit-64bit

I am pulling a JSON object from my API and creating it using the following code (in hindsight not the way to go):

```
+ (YActivity *)instanceFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)jsonDictionary
{
    YActivity * instance = [[YActivity alloc] init];
    [instance setAttributesFromDictionary:jsonDictionary];
    return instance;
}

- (void)setAttributesFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)jsonDictionary
    {
        if (![jsonDictionary isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            return;
        }

        [self setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:jsonDictionary];
}
```

One of the keys is "type". I have a read-only variable @synthesized called "type". On the 32-bit version of my app, this is set right away before `setValue:(id)value forUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key` is called. I reference this value in that method, and on the 64-bit version of my app, when the breakpoint hits this method, type is not set yet.

Clearly this isn't the best course of action. I am just wondering if anyone else as seen this or if I'm barking up the wrong tree. I diffed the files between the two versions and they are identical. I am running them both on iOS 8.1 Simulator, the API is returning the same thing for both...I'm stumped. Basically on the old version defined keys are set before undefined, and on the new version it seems the opposite of that.

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered collections; code should never make assumptions about the order in which a dictionary's keys will be enumerated.

Comment: Yes as noted, clearly incorrect here. Wondering if anyone knows if the order of these methods changed at some point. Relying on the serialization of dictionaries is incorrect.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by 'order of these methods.' The hashes produced by various different object types may be different on 64 vs. 32 bit systems, so that would probably account for the difference you're seeing.

Comment: Per CFDictionary.c, the bucket size also varies between the 32- and 64-bit runtime. Apple has exercised its non-guarantee of object order.

Comment: @Tommy Thanks, i assumed that was the case, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything...now to fix the code so not relying on this anyways!

Comment: @jlehr thanks for your help! Need to fix the code anyways, was just curious.

Comment: @JeffN A couple of potential quick fixes: 1) Instead of calling `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:`, call `setValue:forKey:` from a loop in which you enumerate the keys yourself; that way you can order the keys the way you like; or 2) Before calling `setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:`, create a mutable copy of the dictionary, remove the key-value pair for `type`, call `setValue:forKey:` with `type` and its value; then you can safely pass the mutable dictionary instead of the original one.

Comment: @jlehr I went with the former solution, if you would like to mark as a answer I will approve, but as you said its a quick fix, i will be re-architecting this class. thanks again.

Comment: Even on a given system, there was no assurance that the order would always be the same.  I've seen it change from one run to the next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSDictionary` objects are unordered collections, so code should never make assumptions about the order in which a dictionary will enumerate its own keys. It turns out that there are implementation differences between the 32- and 64-bit runtimes that affect where hashed values end up being stored.

Since the API contract explicitly doesn't guarantee order, that shouldn't cause problems, but it can (and in this case apparently *does*) have the side-effect of causing code that formerly 'worked' to break when compiled for the 64-bit architecture.

A quick way to fix the problem you're currently having without significantly changing the implementation would be to enumerate the dictionary's keys yourself, which would allow you to provide an array of keys ordered however you wish:

```
- (void)setAttributesFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    // So instead of doing this...
    //
    // [self setValuesForKeysWithDictionary:dictionary];

    // You could do something along these lines:
    //
    NSMutableArray *keys = dictionary.allKeys.mutableCopy;

    // TODO: insert code to change the order of the keys array.
    // Then loop through the keys yourself...

    for (NSString *key in keys)
    {
        [self setValue:dictionary[key] forKey:key];
    }
}
```